# I have this problem in my code for Lambda AWS KeyError

Tags: python, aws-lambda, keyerror

I have this "KeyError" in lambda with python and i cant find problem is a code python for make request in S3 code for run SNS of Compliance of  Device Defender

````
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 696, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 677, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 728, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in <module>\n    myDeviceJobDocument_DEVICE_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRING_CHECK = os.environ['https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/'] + \"/certRotateJob.json\"\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py\", line 681, in __getitem__\n    raise KeyError(key) from None\n"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 0270cd0c-1e14-4cc9-8042-7f0ef5347013 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] KeyError: 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in <module>
    myDeviceJobDocument_DEVICE_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRING_CHECK = os.environ['https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/'] + "/certRotateJob.json"
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
END RequestId: 0270cd0c-1e14-4cc9-8042-7f0ef5347013
REPORT RequestId: 0270cd0c-1e14-4cc9-8042-7f0ef5347013  Duration: 5199.31 ms    Billed Duration: 5200 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 34 MB  
Unknown application error occurred```
````

Comment: Always better to include relevant source code (as well as the exception info) than to simply dump a stack trace into your post and ask people to diagnose problems in the missing code.

Comment: @jarmod If you did not know, just not answer this is not a code but one output, some times people do not want expose their code, and normally is not necessary,

Comment: In the general case, Stack Overflow expects you to provide a minimally reproducible example, with code. That's why I suggested that it is better to include 'relevant' code. There's no requirement to post all the code and obviously that wouldn't be good for you (disclosure reasons) and not good for Stack Overflow (the post would be too long and complex). Also, maintaining a high standard of questions, as well as answers, is in the interest of all current, and future, Stack Overflow users, yourself included.

Comment: @ jarmod I am not here because of Stack Overflow, and I have made one question if not know or do not understand pass for what you could answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of your code:

```py
myDeviceJobDocument_DEVICE_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRING_CHECK = os.environ['https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/'] + "/certRotateJob.json"
```

attempts to look up the value of an environment variable called `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/`. This doesn't look like a valid name for an environment variable, so it probably doesn't exist, which would indeed cause a `KeyError`.